# SSRS: passing a multivalue parameter to a query

Tags: reporting-services, google-bigquery

I have an SSRS report based on a BigQuery database. the main query uses parameters as arguments and is supposed to accept multiple values for each argument.

The query has the following structure :

```
select 
field1,field2
from
tableName
where
field1 in (?)
```

And the parameter value of the argument ? is :

```
=Join(Parameters!P_MyParam.Value,",")
```

When I run the report, the filter works only if one single value of **P_MyParam** is selected. If I select two values for example, no results are displayed (even if each of the two values gives results if used separately).

When I try the formula:

```
="'" & Join(Parameters!P_MyParam.Value,"','") & "'"
```

no results are shown at all (even if one single value of the parameter is selected).

I tried to use filters instead of parameters but it leads to the error : **System.OutOfMemoryException.**

Is there an efficient way to pass multiple values to a parameter when the used database is BigQuery ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
You can pass the parameter as a comma separated string and then split it in the where clause. You don't have to format the parameter at all.

CREATE PROC [dbo].[example_procedure]
(
    @CheckDateFrom DATE         = NULL
   , @CheckDateTo   DATE         = NULL
   , @BankCode       VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
)
AS
 
   BEGIN
 
       SELECT 
            [c].[BANK_CODE]
           , [c].[CHECK_DATE]
           , [c].[CHECK_NUM]
       FROM 
          [dbo].[CHECK] AS [c] 
       WHERE
         1=1
         AND c.[CHECK_DATE] BETWEEN @CheckDateFrom AND @CheckDateTo 
         AND c.[BANK_CODE] IN(SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@BankCode, ',') WHERE RTRIM(value) != '');
 
   END;
```

Solution 2:

```
You can do a Boolean filter in the dataset.

Expression =IIF(InStr(("'" + Join(Parameters!BankCode.Value, "', '") + "'"), ("'" + Trim(Fields!BANK_CODE.Value) + "'") ) > 0, True, False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks aduguid, it did work !

I added the parameter using the following formula :
=Join(Parameters!MyParam.Value,",")

then I included it in the query as you suggested using the commands unnest and split:

...
...
where field1 in unnest(SPLIT(?,','))

Thanks again,

Comment: No worries, anytime